# How to use imagemagick to give background and dimensions to my screenshot?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am new to Image Magick but am trying to get it to convert my image to a size and background pleasant for Twitter. The qualities I'm going for are as follows:

- my overall canvas size 16:9, so about 1200x675
- my actual screenshot centered and about 3/4 the width
- background texture of my choosing

  My latest attempt is with the following, but it doesn't seem to actually make any noticeable changes.

```
convert ds.png -adaptive-resize 1200 -size 1200x675 -texture ~/Pictures/DoctorWho/horizon.jpg -gravity Center ds.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Imagemagick 6, Unix syntax, if you just want to resize a small background image, then try

```
convert \( background.suffix -resize 1200x675 \) \( foreground.suffix -resize x506 \) -gravity center -compose over -composite result.suffix
```

If you want to crop a large image for the background, then try

```
convert \( background.suffix -gravity center -crop 1200x675+0+0 +repage \) \( foreground.suffix -resize x506 \) -gravity center -compose over -composite result.suffix
```

If you need to tile out a small image for the background, then

```
convert \( -size 1200x675 tile:background.suffix \) \( foreground.suffix -resize x506 \) -gravity center -compose over -composite result.suffix
```

For Windows remove the \ from the parentheses.

For Imagemagick 7, replace convert with magick.